# C# custom types?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine, types

I'm working on a calculator that uses polynomials, and I was wondering if I could make some sort of "custom type" to use instead of and array of lists of strings.

So, for example, instead of `List<string>[] polynomial` I'd like to write `Polynomial polynomial`, where the `Polynomial` type is a `List<string>[]` (which means I could use it the same exact way I currently use the `List<string>[]`, so, for example, I could access the values with polynomial[n][i] like I do now)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [Inheritance in C# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance)

Comment: *Polynomial type is a List<string>[]* - mm, I think i'd say *has a* rather than *is a*

Comment: *I could use it the same exact way I currently* - and what way is that?

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode! I finally finished implementing this into my code and it actually works very well

Comment: Inheritance is a bad idea here. Encapsulation is a better one.

Comment: do you mean List<Polynomial>[] polynomial

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII - Are you asking me? If so, encapsulation would be `public class Polynomial { private List<string>[] _internal; }`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by @BionicCode I used an inheritant Polynomial class

```
public class Polynomial : List<List<string>>
{

}
```

and it works as expected. I did have to change `List<string>[]` to `List<List<string>>` beacuse otherwise it would throw a "invalid base type" error, but it still functions the same way:

```
Polynomial polynomial;
```

to create a new variable and

```
polynomial[n][i]
```

to access its values.

To instantiate a new Polynomial I use

```
polynomial = new Polynomial();
    
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    polynomial.Add(new List<string>());
}
```

Comment: It's not a great solution because the outside world can manipulate your polynomial's internals. You don't want that. `public class Polynomial { private List<string>[] internals; }` is a better approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt has over 1500 upvotes and the answer over 1700 upvotes :)

Comment: @tymtam - And the answer says NOT to inherit from list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer shows inheriting from a list.

Comment: @tymtam - Yes, it does, but the text says not to. "`List<T>` is a mechanism. Football team is a business object -- that is, an object that represents some concept that is in the business domain of the program. Don't mix those!"

Comment: @tymtam - "So make a property called `Roster` that is a `List<Player>`."

Comment: @tymtam - "You spent more time typing up your question that it would have taken you to write forwarding methods for the relevant members of `List<T>` fifty times over. You're clearly not afraid of verbosity, and we are talking about a very small amount of code here; this is a few minutes work."

Comment: @tymtam - "I gave it some more thought and there is another reason to not model a football team as a list of players."

Comment: @Enigmativity I think we have a case of a bad comment and a mistaken identity. I'm not the OP and my comment was meant to mean that this solution is bad.

Comment: @tymtam - Sorry if I've misunderstood. I thought you were suggesting that the linked answer was supporting inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code for Polynomial class.

```
public class Polynomial
{
    public List<Monomial> monomials = new List<Monomial>();

    public Polynomial(List<Monomial> allMonomials)
    {
        monomials = allMonomials;
    }

    public Polynomial()
    {
        monomials = new List<Monomial>();
    }
}
```

And use the code below for Monomial class.

```
    public class Monomial
{
    public List<string> items = new List<string>();

    public Monomial()
    {
        items = new List<string>();
    }

    public Monomial(List<string> allItems)
    {
        items = allItems;
    }
}
```

To sum up, you can create new objects of Monomial and Polynomial as simple as you can see in the following code

```
List<Monomial> monomials = new List<Monomial>();
monomials.Add(new Monomial(new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C"}));
monomials.Add(new Monomial());
Polynomial polynomial = new Polynomial();
Polynomial polynomial2 = new Polynomial(monomials);
```

Comment: What does this give you that `List<string>[]` doesn't?

Comment: I mean I get the same result just by writing `List<string>[] polynomial = new[] { new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" } };`.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's semi true. Actually it is `List<List<string>>` so more dynamic and .. well, tbh, it is exactly what OP is asking for ^^ You could still add the relevant methods/properties/indexer for adding, editing items safer without directly exposing the lists themselves etc but basically that's it

Comment: @derHugo - What the OP asked for and what's a good idea might be two different things.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's true .. but this doesn't mean this answer is bad per se .. it is the question/OP's intent that is probably bad but this answer (as the other one) valid attempts to answer this .. whether they are highly controversial is another question ;)